# Globalize.js number format doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery-globalize

The following fails with an error inside number.js when it tries to pass a non-existent pattern to another function. AFAIK I have loaded all dependencies and cldr data for this.

```
function formatHours(val) {
   if (val == null) return "";
   var num = Number(val);
   util.msAlert(val + ": " + typeof num);
   if (val == 0) return num;
   return Globalize.formatNumber(
      num, 
      {  minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1 }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understood the root cause of your problem. But, follow a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/t9he43Lk/1/ that formats a number. Feel free to change `num` and `options` to better suite your needs.

```
var num, formattedNum, options;

loadCldr();

num = Math.PI;
//options = { minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1 };
formattedPI = Globalize("en").formatNumber(num, options);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = formattedPI;

function loadCldr() {
   ...
}
```

If you have any questions, please just let me know.